# Json response print student name

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get name of student details.
I have tried this code but its not working.
please help me out.

I want to get student name as well as department.

```
var response = '[
    {
        "student": {
            "id": "12",
                "departmant" :  "computer",
            "created_date": "2015-04-16 12:05:27",
            "modified_date": "2015-04-16 12:05:27"
        },
        "student_details": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "student_id": "12",
                "lname": "jain",
                "name": "hemant",
                "created_date": "2015-04-16 12:05:27",
                "modified_data": "2015-04-16 12:05:27"
            }
        ]
    }
]';

var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(codes);
$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  alert(value.name);
});
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I don't think response is a valid JSON object as it starts with [ and ends with ].

Comment: so, i need to change my response ? right? Actually m new in json

Comment: @Piwwoli the JSON is valid, [] means it's an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON should be valid, but you're trying to access a level too far up. the structure of that JSON is

```
Array(Object(key:value))
```

you are trying to access

```
Object(key:value)
```

so to archieve what you want, you'll need to do the following:

```
var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(codes);
$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  //key will be 0, since there's only one record in the array
  $.each(value, function (key2, value2) {
       alert(value2.name); // which won't be defined for the first entry (student)
  }
});
```

or

```
var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(codes);
$.each(codes[0], function (key, value) {
  alert(value.name); // which still won't be defined for the first entry (student)
});
```

or, the more sensefull way:

```
var codes = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(codes);
$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
  alert(value.student.id);
  alert(value.student_details.name);
});
```

Comment: hello..Mr.Manhattan
I have tried  
$.each(codes, function (key, value) {
     alert(value.MovementTrackingHeader.id);
     alert(value.MovementTrackingDetail.sub_sequence_id);
     });
I am getting  alert(value.student.id); BUT   alert(value.student_details.name); is getiing undefied... thank for ur response.